# Scala Actor: ReceiveTimeout with Param

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Is it possible to pass a parameter to ReceiveTimeout? I have the following  code:

```
case ReceiveTimeout =>
      self ! BuildJobEvents(asperaClient.getWorkOrder(workOrderID), dateTime)
```

When I try to pass a parameter, but that is not valid. I looked at the [documentation here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html), and did not see anything about using parameters either. Is it possible to pass a parameter to ReceiveTimeout? If not, how would I get around this?

**Edit**

I have an actor system that will log events to a table. Each event has a timestamp noting when it occurs. I need to pass this timestamp along the chain, so I can use it to determine if data (which has an updated_at timestamp) has actually changed.

Ex: 
When I call the API service, say I get an event like this:

```
Item {
  event1 {
    stated: 5:00pm,
    completed: 5:10pm
  },
  event1 {
    stated: 5:10pm
  }
  data: data
  updated_at: 5:11pm
}
```

I want to log event1 and event2 here. I also want to pass a dateTime value of 5:11 pm in the message, so we can use it for the next call:

```
Item {
  event1 {
    stated: 5:00pm,
    completed: 5:10pm
  },
  event1 {
    stated: 5:10pm,
    completed: 5:12pm
  }
  data: data
  updated_at: 5:12pm
}
```

In this case, I do not want to log event1, because the timestamp is before 5:11 and therefore, the actor has already logged it. I would log event2 again though.

Comment: Can you describe your use case? I sense a XY problem here

Comment: why not `context.system.scheduleOnce(...)` the message you actually want? If you receive something else before, you can just `cancel` the `Cancellable` you got from `scheduleOnce`.

Comment: I thought scheduleOnce would only send the message one time "Schedules a message to be sent once with a delay, i.e. a time period that has to pass before the message is sent.". I need this to happen multiple times

Comment: then use `schedule` instead; this won't be exactly equivalent to `setReceiveTimeout` though. As @JeanLogeart commented, better describe your use case.

Comment: I added an edit as well, Maybe that makes more sense?

Comment: It seems like you just want a member variable: `var lastLogTime = ...` that indicates the minimum time to log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for `context.become` which you can use to implement a light weight state machine.

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case something =>
      context.setReceiveTimeout(5.seconds)
      context.become(waitForTimeout(something))
  }

  private[this] def waitForTimeout(param: Any): Receive = {
    case ReceiveTimeout =>
      // do something with something
  }
}
```

You have more possibilities if you mixin the `FSM` trait.

**EDIT**

Reading your event examples, maybe something like this?

```
private def receiveNextEvent(lastTimestamp: DateTime): Receive = {
  case event =>
   if (event.stated > lastTimestamp) {
     logEvent(event)
     context.become(receiveNextEvent(event.stated)
   }
}
```